# ln -s vs mount --bind

Tags: partition, mount, symbolic-link, fstab

Is there any practical difference between using `ln -s` or `mount --bind`?

I want to move some folders to another partition, without changing their daemon setting, and wonder what approach I should take.

I prefer `ln -s` as it requires minimum setup (no `/etc/fstab` modifications), but perhaps there is a reason why it's not common?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Hell yes. If you execute the `ln -s` you create a symbolic link, which is an [inode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) pointing to a certain filesystem object, which is why symlinks can traverse filesystems and hard links cannot: hard links do not have their own inode.

If you mount a filesystem with `--bind`, you create a second *mountpoint* for a device or filesystem.

If you envision a symlink as a redirect, then envision a `--bind` mounted filesystem as creating another gateway to data.

Symlinks and bind mounts are a whole different ballgame.

The `--bind` mount seems a bit more robust to me and it probably is a bit faster than working with a symlink. On the other hand, there are no serious drawbacks to using the symlink, as the performance hit will be small (if it at all exists).

**Edit**: I've been thinking about this, and the performance hit might be a bit bigger than I originally thought. If you have an application that reads a lot of different files, then every new file that is opened will require an extra read. Some research [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link#Storage_of_symbolic_links) suggests that my assumption is correct, so if you have an IO heavy application running there, consider the `--bind` option to mount above the symlink solution.

The reason it is not common, is probably the fact that a symlink is visible in an `ls`, whereas a bind mount is only visible when looking at /proc/mounts or /etc/mtab (which is what the mount command does, if it is executed without parameters). Other than that, I don't think there are any issues. I'd be interested if there are, though.

**Addition**: another issue with `ln -s` is that for some applications, when the path gets dereferenced, it may cause the application to balk if it "expects" certain items to be in specific places.

Comment: Thanks for the through explanation!

A small follow-up question - what --rbind parameter actually does and how it can be used?

From the manual it seems the parameter supports mounting the sub-mounts in the mounted tree is this correct?

Also, is only --rbind enough, or I need to do --bind then --rebind?

Thanks again.

Comment: Seems so. Never used --rbind myself. Try it out, I'd say ;)

Comment: `mount`, when invoked without any arguments, prints the contents of `/etc/mtab`, which has slightly different information than `/proc/mounts`. (In particular, `/proc/mounts` (symlink to `/proc/self/mounts`) always shows the mountpoints visible to the process reading it.)

Comment: Oops. My bad. Fixed.

Comment: Wouldn't caching mostly eliminate any performance hit from the need to repeatedly traverse the symlink?

Comment: Errr... @warren, feel free to rephrase my text if it is not clear, but if you have additions, please add them in a comment.

Comment: @wzzrd - from the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq) "Best of all — edit and improve the existing questions and answers!" :) ..this is by no means a slight to your answer - it is a small improvement with additional information, for which you'll receive additional rep if/when it is voted up :)

Comment: @warren, never mind, I'm not mad :) it's just you added something that I have no idea about, so that felt a bit odd ;)

Comment: @wzzrd - didn't mean to step on any toes :) ..the app-specific issue is something I've run into with the main product I use

Comment: My user folders /home/userx are on a second disk volume, with a symlink for /home. Could or should I replace that symlink with a `mount --rbind /media/userdata/home /home` ? This might fix snap having issues with the symlink.

Answer (score 9):

One of the big differences between `ln -s` and a bind mount is that you can use a bind mount to "modify" a read-only filesystem.  For example, if there were a CD mounted on `/mnt/application`, and you wanted to replace `/mnt/application/badconfigfile.conf` with a correct version, you could do this:

```
mount -o bind /path/to/correct/file.conf /mnt/application/badconfigfile.conf
```

It would not be possible to affect the same change using a symlink because you're not able to modify the target filesystem.

This can also be used to good affect if you distributed a common suite of software via NFS (or some sort of cluster filesystem), and you want to make host-specific changes on one system.  You can simply use a bind mount on the target system to override the files or directories as necessary.

Comment: Headache saver! (rare case, but worth remembering for that special moment)

Answer (score 4):

Practial difference #1 for me between ln -s and mount --bind :

vsftpd doesn't not allow to browse a directory through a symbolic link, but allows when mounted.

I don't know what daemon you're using, but it may behave similarly.

Answer (score 2):

One might note that as a consequence of binding to a mount, which is itself a binding, that is later rebound, the original binding remains intact, assuming everything physically stay connected.

That is, if bind A to B and bind B to C, and then bind D to B, C will still be bound to A. That might be what you want, or not. If one desires C to follow B then remount using the same targets, i.e. `mount -o remount B C`, or use `--rbind` instead. There is no `--rebind` option.